# Disable noise cancellation for microphone in Android (1.5)?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, microphone, android-1.5-cupcake

Is it possible to disable noise cancellation for the microphone in Android (specifically 1.5) via code?

I want to create a dumb MicrophoneApp that records all the background noises, but I believe that noise cancellation for the microphone is getting in the way. I know you can do it if you root your phone and edit settings (ie [this article](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=6787214)), but I want to make it **without** root the phone.

Comment: I am amazed that almost a year went by and you didn't receive any answer. I am now having a similar question. +1.

Comment: And now two years have gone by.

Comment: I think Android 1.5 is too old for now, very few developers developing for API level 3. If you are looking solution for any API level, you should edit your question and remove OS 1.5, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Noise filters in audio recording sources on Android vary greatly from device to device. It isn't until Ice Cream Sandwich that any sort of definition was put into the device compatibility document defining a method for not having filtering. That method id to use the MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION audio source. Before that it's just choose a setting and hope for the best. I've found that some devices work better with MIC and some with VOICE_RECOGNITION prior to 4.0. HTC seems to have started the use fo VOICE_RECOGNITION as a no-filter zone pre-ICS.

Since there is no loop-back audio interface you can't even detect it but you can surface different audio paths to the user to choose from.

Answer (score -1):

i dont think without rooting the phone you can change microphone behaviour. noise cancellation is more a function of second microphone than some software, and to alter some hardware you would require super user privileges.

Comment: This may be great, but since it doesn't answer the OP (as he specifically points out he doesn't want to root), you certainly aren't getting the bounty, mate.

Comment: lol.. its ok.. ;-)  ..  no problem mate.. but the "i dont want to root" condition looks like  " i dont want to work but i want money " problem . i dont think its possible without a root.  i guess your bounty aint going anywhere that way

Comment: Well his answer is, no you cannot do it. So if he is correct he should receive the bounty.

Answer (score -3):

Ok, noise detection and cancellation is done using two microphones and android simply differentiate both signals coming from each one of them and get the right signal of the speaker, Sony Ericsson Neo have the noise mic in the back of the phone, simply you can disable the second mic and you will get the full signal.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP though. Please re-read the question and show some actual code.

Comment: this is simply my idea and depends on your hardware, just google how to disable the noise mic in the phone.

Comment: that's great - but this question is in relation to general android, not a specific device.